# event declared after login in liferay

Tags: liferay

I work  with liferay 5.2  and tomcat 6

I want to save the idportal  and date login  when the user connect to my application which

is depolyed in liferay

I should find the event that is responsible of login

I alreay used a code which will make an update after this event :**onAfterCreate**

```
import com.liferay.portal.model.User;
.........
........
 public void onAfterCreate(User user)
    throws ModelListenerException
  {
    System.out.println("-------------- User Creation::" + user.getScreenName());
    try
    {
      Employee employee = getEmployee(user.getScreenName());

      if (employee != null)
        updateEmployee(employee, user, false);
      else
        updateEmployee(new Employee(), user, true);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

so I should use same code like the previous code

the idportal is :**user.getScreenName()**

date login I think is **user.getLastLoginDate()**

but I didn't find the event which will be decalared after login

**Updated** :

I followed yours steps

in liferay-hook.xml I add this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hook PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Hook 6.1.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-hook_6_1_0.dtd">

<hook>
    <portal-properties>portal.properties</portal-properties>
</hook>
```

and in portal.properties  I add

```
login.events.post=com.liferay.hooks.user.LoginPostAction
```

and I create java class :  LoginPostAction.java

```
package com.liferay.hooks.user;


import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.Action;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.ActionException;



public class LoginPostAction  

{

    public void run(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ActionException {

        System.out.println("  the user is connected ");
    }



}
```

in this example the import  import com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.Action;  is unused

as you see I want with this code to display message after login

but when I deploy this example I have this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.liferay.hooks.user.LoginPostAction cannot be cast to com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.Action
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HookHotDeployListener.initEvent(HookHotDeployListener.java:591)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HookHotDeployListener.initEvents(HookHotDeployListener.java:643)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HookHotDeployListener.doInvokeDeploy(HookHotDeployListener.java:237)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HookHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(HookHotDeployListener.java:98)
    ... 31 more
```

**updated :**

I want to display the ScreenName and login date of user connected ,

I already used this code to display ScreenName `user.getScreenName()`  and for login date I think that I should use `user.getLastLoginDate(`)  and I use this import

```
import com.liferay.portal.model.User;
```

but I didn't find th way to use this code in **the run function**

```
package com.liferay.hooks.user;


import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.Action;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.ActionException;



public class LoginPostAction extends Action

{

    public void run(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ActionException {

        System.out.println("  the user is connected ");

     // here I want to display the ScreenName and login date of user connected
    }



}
```

I try with this code :

```
package com.liferay.hooks.user;


import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.Action;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.ActionException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.WebKeys;
import com.liferay.portal.model.User;
import com.liferay.portal.theme.ThemeDisplay;




public class LoginPostAction extends Action 

{

    public void run(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ActionException {

        System.out.println("  the user is connected ");
        ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
        User user = themeDisplay.getUser();
        System.out.println("user "+user.getScreenName());

    }



}
```

and I make in portal.properties  this code :

```
login.events.post=com.liferay.hooks.user.LoginPostAction
servlet.service.events.post=com.liferay.hooks.user.LoginPostAction
```

but I have this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.liferay.hooks.user.LoginPostAction.run(LoginPostAction.java:25)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.InvokerAction.run(InvokerAction.java:52)
    at com.liferay.portal.events.EventsProcessorImpl.processEvent(EventsProcessorImpl.java:92)
```

Answer (score 2):

The listener you're using is the "model listener" and they're used for add\update\delete events.

To listen to a login event. You can do the following:

1. In your `liferay-hook.xml` file add `portal-properties` to the `hook` element. For example,

   ```
   <hook>
       <portal-properties>portal.properties</portal-properties>
   </hook>
   ```
2. Then create `/docroot/WEB-INF/src/portal.properties`.
3. Add the line:

   ```
   login.events.post=com.test.events.LoginPostAction
   ```
4. Then extend the `com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.Action`.
5. Implement:

   ```
   public void run(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
       throws ActionException;
   ```

Comment: @franco you're missing step 4 in your updated question - and the error message clearly says so

Comment: thank you very much, now I want to display the ScreenName and login date of user connected, I updated my question

Comment: I have error NullPointerException  when I use the previous code

Comment: Remove: `servlet.service.events.post=com.liferay.hooks.user.LoginPostAction`. It will run every time Struts process a request which may or may not have a logged in user.